# Sequential column aggregations in dataframe causes rows to shrink

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a df_test dataframe and want to do multiple aggregation steps to it.

```
df_test=
[id,date,visit_number,purchase_amount]
[1,01-01-2019,4,70]
[1,01-04-2019,5,30]
[2,01-01-2019,1,10]

Desired Output table should be this (note: date calculatios are inclusive of upper and lower date!):

df_final=
[id,date_delta,visits,purchase_amount]
[1,4,2,100]
[2,1,1,10 ]
```

I aggregated in the following way but due to sequential aggregation, I suspect that I am losing rows at each step...How can this be prevented?

```
#for the dataframe, find the date delta for each id.
df_1=df_test.groupby(['id'])["date"].apply(lambda z : z.max()-z.min()).reset_index()

#for the dataframe, find the delta of the visitnumber for each id.
df_2=df_test.groupby(['id'])["visit_number"].apply(lambda y : y.max()-y.min()).astype(int).reset_index()

#for the dataframe, find the sum of purchases for each id.
df_3=df_test.groupby(['id'])["purchas_amount"].apply(lambda x : x.astype(int).sum()).reset_index()
```

With this approach, I lost 50% of my rows! Please help in what to do ir is this expected due to aggregation? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider one call to [`groupby().agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with needed aggregate functions in a dictionary include a customized one for *date_delta*. Also, `set_axis` used to rename columns:

```
def date_delta(g):
    return pd.Timedelta((g.max() - g.min()) + pd.Timedelta(days=1)).days

agg_df = (df_test.groupby('id')
                 .agg({'date': date_delta,
                       'visit_number':'count',
                       'purchase_amount':'sum'})
                 .set_axis(['date_delta', 'visits', 'purchase_amount'],
                           axis='columns', inplace=False)
         )

print(agg_df)
#     date_delta  visits  purchase_amount
# id                                     
# 1            4       2              100
# 2            1       1               10
```

Data

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame([[1,'01-01-2019',4,70],
                        [1,'01-04-2019',5,30],
                        [2,'01-01-2019',1,10]],
                       columns = ['id','date','visit_number','purchase_amount'])
df_test['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_test['date'])
print(df_test)
```